# Shrink Trackpad on Macbook running Mojave

Tags: macbook-pro, mojave, trackpad

I am running mojave (10.14.2) on a 2018 macbook. I keep accidentally hitting the trackpad while typing. None of the solutions in [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/210936/how-to-disable-accidental-trackpad-input-in-yosemite) still work. Does an updated solution exist?

Comment: so the physical tape solution doesn't work? also do you use tap-to-click mode? If so check out https://gist.github.com/lacostenycoder/e57e33258ba30a7a39122a3931669075

Comment: I don't want to physically tape over my touchbar. I still need its functions. How do I use that script you linked to?

Comment: I've updated my answer to explain how to use the script.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution I've found which works on any recent version of MacOS is turn off `tap to click` in `System Preferences > Trackpad > Point & Click`.

You can use [this applescript](https://gist.github.com/lacostenycoder/e57e33258ba30a7a39122a3931669075) to quickly toggle tap-to-click on and off. On MacOS open `Applications > Utilities > Script Editor` and paste the code from this script:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal anchor "trackpadTab" of pane "com.apple.preference.trackpad"
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences"
    click checkbox 3 of tab group 1 of window 1
end tell
quit application "System Preferences"
```

Then select `File > Export` and save in `Applications` but also make sure to select `File Format > Application` before saving.

If you want to make it very easy to run the toggle on and off, you may want to [add a custom keyboard shortcut](http://osxdaily.com/2017/08/08/create-custom-keyboard-shortcut-mac/) which would just run the toggle application.